# Gulp Watch Concat sometimes ignores some JS files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a Gulp concat watch task setup to concat some JS files:

```
var sources = [
  'public/js/scriptA.js',
  'public/js/scriptB.js',
  'public/js/scriptC.js',
  'public/js/scriptD.js',
  'public/js/scriptE.js'
];

gulp.task('main.js', function(){
    return gulp.src(sources)
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(sources, ['main.js']);
});
```

Pretty normal setup I think. Whenever any of the scripts change, the `main.js` is created by concatenating the scripts in that order. It works fine 99% of the time.

But sometimes, maybe randomly, the concat simply leaves out 1 or more of the files. I'll be editing `scriptB.js` for example, save it, then look at `main.js` and it concat'ed only `scriptA`, `scriptB` and `scriptE`. It completely left out C and D. And sometimes it might just be C. Sometimes it might be D. Sometimes it might be A. It's just random. I didn't do anything to any of the files it leaves out. I have it opened in my editor but it's unchanged and just sitting there. Gulp just decides to leave it out for some random reason sometimes.

The way I fix it is to simply open up whatever script was left out and add a space to the end of a random line or something and then save it, then the `main.js` is concatenated like I'd expect it. There was nothing wrong with the file. Just had to resave it.

Is this an outstanding bug to anyone's knowledge? I haven't been able to find any of info on this bug anywhere. Is there anything I can do to debug or log this issue to figure out how to recreate it?

One thing I did notice, was, lets say I was editing `scriptC` and save it, and then notice `scriptD` was missing. If I go back to `scriptC` and save it again, `scriptD` is still not concatenated in. I HAVE to open up `scriptD` and save it to force it to be included back into the `main.js`. So once I see the problem popup, I can typically recreate it in this manner.

This typically only happens about 1 in 20 saves.

Comment: Your ``gulp.watch`` line refers to ``sources.js.main``... I assume you were just simplifying things to just use ``sources`` but you missed one?

Comment: Yes I was, correcting. Like I said, the concat works great most of the time.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are seeing the same problem and it can sometimes be 'fixed' temporarily by changing the order of the scripts. Definitely an issue somewhere.

Comment: I never did find a resolution to this no. Usually I just resave the file that gets left out and that somehow fixes it. It's a really weird and random problem. And I'm not sure how to use gulp to debug it and see the problem.

Comment: Did you log this issue on the concat github page? https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat/issues

Comment: Yes long ago: https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat/issues/54

Answer (score 2):

You could use the gulp-include Plugin to get rid of the Problem. With this Plugin you can include/require your js-files by using special comments in the main.js file.

main.js:

```
//=require 'public/js/scriptA.js' 
//=require 'public/js/scriptB.js' 
//=require 'public/js/scriptC.js' 
//=require 'public/js/scriptD.js' 
//=require 'public/js/scriptE.js'
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp          = require("gulp"),
    include       = require("gulp-include");

gulp.task("scripts", function() { 

    gulp.src("main.js")
        .pipe(include())
            .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/js"));

});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(sources, ['main.js']);
});
```

The Plugin is available via npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include